# How to put the expression in Quicksort's A[]

Tags: c, quicksort

This is sorting algorithm. I try to sort in descending order according to the size of the sum (x+y) of the fields which has x and y in struct.

I make the Quicksort descending order. but I have a question how to handle the sum(x+y) of the fields.

```
typedef struct DATA { double x; double y; double sum} DTYPE;

#define DTYPE double

#define SWAP(aa,bb) {DTYPE tmp; tmp = aa; aa=bb; bb=tmp;}

 

void sort_201821100(DTYPE A[], int N)

{

int piv;

if (N > 1) {

piv = partition(A, N);

sort_201821100(A, piv);

sort_201821100(A + piv + 1, N - piv - 1);

}

}

 

int partition(DTYPE A[], int N) {

int P = N / 2;

int i = 0, j = N;

 

// I need DType.sum struct variable which has sum of DType.x and DType.y, But I have no idea how to implement this line on partition function 

A[].sum = A[].x + A[].y;  

 

DTYPE pivot;

SWAP(A[N / 2].sum, A[0].sum);

pivot = A[0].sum;

while (1) {

while ((A[++i].sum > pivot) && (i < N));

while ((A[--j].sum < pivot) && (j > 0));

if (i >= j) break;

SWAP(A[i], A[j]);

}

SWAP(A[0], A[j]);

return j;

}
```

I want to know how to put the expression in A[].sum on partition function.

Any reply will be thankful. Best regards.

[UPDATE]

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        A[i].sum = A[i].x + A[i].y;
    }
```

I inserted `for` codes into the sources. but the error is thrown.

```
Expression must have a struct or union type.
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop?

Comment: Yes. Won't that work?

Comment: I did. but the error is thrown. Expression must have a struct or union type.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a lot of errors.

```
typedef struct DATA { double x; double y; double sum} DTYPE;

#define DTYPE double
```

You are redefining the type of `DTYPE` as `double`. That's the reason why the `for` loop I suggested isn't working. The error thrown stating

```
Member must be a stuct or union
```

is because of this *redefinition*, now `DTYPE` becomes a `double`. So doing something like `double.sum` is illegal C code.

Remove/change that line `#define DTYPE double`.

Also, you are doing this:

```
DTYPE pivot;
:
pivot = A[0].sum;
```

You are trying to assign `A[0].sum` (of type `double`) to `pivot` which is of type `struct DATA`.

For your original question, you need to use a `for` loop as:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    A[i].sum = A[i].x + A[i].y;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Luna ***if*** this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.